# Tree traversal, Recursion

Tags: c, data-structures, recursion, tree

I was wondering how the following code traverse the tree :

```
//pre order travel 
void travel (BST *tree)
{ 
    the
    if(tree!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ",tree->info); 
        travel(tree->left);
        travel(tree->right);
    }
}
```

I   am getting confused with the recursive calling of  `travel(tree->left)` and `travel(tree->right)`.
If I have :

```
        A
    B       C
  D       E   F
```

How `travel(tree->left)` and `travel(tree->right)` get terminated side by side travel the tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we apply the order of print then left then right so:

```
    A prints goes left


     B prints goes left
        D prints goes left

        D back left goes right

        D back right
     B back left goes right

     B back right

    A back left goes right
```

and so on...

so you get:

> A B D C E F